# Unable to get result of pubnub.time() in Python

Tags: python, pubnub

How do I get the result of pubnub.time() when called? This is definitely related to me not fully knowing python that well...

I'm trying to call pubnub.time() to test when network connectivity restores so pubnub can reconnect and I can resubscribe to the necessary channel. I can't seem to get the desired output. Per the [pubnub docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/api-reference-misc#time), time() has 3 methods that will return an int, string, or date.

```
envelope = pubnub.time()

envelope.int()  outputs error
envelope.str()  outputs error
envelope.date_time()  outputs error
```

The only thing that I can get to work is `print(envelope)` which yields `<pubnub.endpoints.time.Time object at 0x75fb8f50>`.

I won't delve into how many iterations of things I've tried on this, and come begging for help.

**UPDATE**

We have a couple remote systems that we're wanting to use PubNub to gather data points from hardware that's connected to the machine. Data requests will come in, and PubNub needs to respond to the requests. Our main issue is that these remote locations have very flaky DSL that goes down for hours to days at a time, and while our python app is still running, PubNub does not reconnect. Trying reconnect_policy with LINEAR and EXPONENTIAL both fail to reconnect after an internet outage. Small, short outages will recover though. Aside from this, PubNub works great for this setup.

Here's my setup config

```
pnconfig = PNConfiguration()
pnconfig.subscribe_key = 'sub'
pnconfig.publish_key = 'pub'
pnconfig.reconnect_policy = 'PNReconnectionPolicy.EXPONENTIAL'
pnconfig.daemon = True
pnconfig.ssl = True
```

Here's our subscribe call back:

```
class MySubscribeCallback(SubscribeCallback):
    def presence(self, pubnub, presence):
        pass

    def status(self, pubnub, status):
        if status.is_error():
            logger.error("PN Error" + str(status.error_data.exception))

        if status.category == 
            PNStatusCategory.PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory:
            logger.error("PN Unexpected Disconnect")
            pubnub.reconnect()
            pass

        elif status.category == PNStatusCategory.PNConnectedCategory:
            logger.info("PN Connected")

        elif status.category == PNStatusCategory.PNReconnectedCategory:
            logger.warning("PN Re-Connected")
            pubnub.subscribe().channels('devChannel').execute()
            pass

        elif status.category == PNStatusCategory.PNDecryptionErrorCategory:
            logger.error("PN Decryption Error")
            pass
```

Comment: Are you setting up the API key configuration?

Comment: You shouldn't need to call time to ping PubNub and you really shouldn't do that. What is your use case details? Publish, subscribe, etc? The more the better. And what @exitcomestothis said.

Comment: @KristopherIves - Yes, here's my setup config 
pnconfig = PNConfiguration()
pnconfig.subscribe_key = 'sub'
pnconfig.publish_key = 'pub'
pnconfig.reconnect_policy = 'PNReconnectionPolicy.EXPONENTIAL'
pnconfig.daemon = True
pnconfig.ssl = True

Comment: @CraigConover - PN is going to be running on a remote device that's gathering data points off of some hardware connected to it, so it will be pub and sub. As a request for data comes in, it responds with the results.

These locations don't have the greatest DSL, and during testing if we simulate the internet going down for more than 30mins, PN never recovers and doesn't resubscribe. This happens even with reconnect set to linear and exponential.

Comment: @exitcomestothis thank you for reporting!  This feels like a PubNub SDK bug. The subscription shouldn't disappear.

Comment: @StephenBlum - Can I provide any additional data or log files on this? If it helps, I'm using Python 2.7.9.

Comment: @exitcomestothis - please report full details, logs, errors, versions, etc. to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) and include a link to this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PubNub SDK Reconnect on Network Error

PubNub SDKs are built durable and are able to maintain socket connections during unstable network conditions.  While connectivity may not always be available, as soon as network connectivity returns, the PubNub SDK should automatically recreate the socket and download any missed messages.  The PubNub Python SDK should be following this philosophy.

In your example code it appears you are setting the `reconnect_policy`.  However your code is setting the reconnect policy variable to a string of `'PNReconnectionPolicy.EXPONENTIAL'` rather than the *enum* `PNReconnectionPolicy.EXPONENTIAL`.

Try the following modification to your code to leverage the reconnection policy:

```py
from pubnub.enums import PNReconnectionPolicy       ## <-- Import Enumerator
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration

## ... init ...

## Set Reconnection Policy using Enumerator
pnconf.reconnect_policy = PNReconnectionPolicy.EXPONENTIAL
```

The SDK's default is *`pnconf.reconnect_policy = PNReconnectionPolicy.NONE`*.  Another valid option is **`pnconf.reconnect_policy = PNReconnectionPolicy.LINEAR`**.

Set to `PNReconnectionPolicy.LINEAR` for automatic reconnects. Use option `PNReconnectionPolicy.NONE` to disable automatic reconnects. Use option `PNReconnectionPolicy.EXPONENTIAL` to set exponential retry interval.

Reference material: https://github.com/pubnub/python/search?q=PNReconnectionPolicy&unscoped_q=PNReconnectionPolicy

Documentation material: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/api-reference-configuration#configuration-args-1

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my novice python mistake, this resolved the disconnect/reconnect issue.

However, one thing I've noticed is that once network connection is restored, the log file for our script is constantly logged with errors saying that PN can't connect. But these only appear after PN has already re-established network connectivity.

ERROR - PN ErrorConnection Error: ('Connection aborted.', error("(104, 'ECONNRESET')",))

This error persists every 5-30 mins and has for the last week. Using PNReconnectionPolicy.EXPONENTIAL.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty awful bug!  An explosion of error log lines, ouch.

Comment: @exitcomestothis bug reports: send email to support@pubnub.com to submit this as an official bug.  I've notified support to watch for your email.

Comment: Thanks for your help on solving this issue. After trying to replicate the logging issue with support, this has to be an issue on our end.

Thanks again for all your help, this has definitely accelerated our integration with PubNub :-)